# Contradiction about "app_exception" event name in firebase console and Crashlytics numbers

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

According to google documentation, "app_exception" event name, counts when the app crashes or throws an exception. This means that app_exception count is larger than app crashes only. Because "app_exception" counts crashes and throws an exception together.

In my firebase console, app_exception users count is +500 , but total crashlytics affected users is 600 in last 90 days.

Does anyone know that what did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. The reason for the differences in these could be multiple factors all stemming from the same root cause. Analytics is used to calculate app_exception events and not Crashlytics.

- If you migrated from Fabric to Firebase, then there could be more users with the Crashlytics SDK than the Analytics SDK, this means that the number would be lower.
- Also possible that because these are two different SDKs they are catching crashes differently. Usually we see Crashlytics as lower, but there are cases where Analytics would be.

Thanks!